# How the value of T(1,0)=T(0,1)=3 in the Random sheepwalk problem?

Tags: algorithm

I have gone through the below codejam question. I could not solve it on my own. So I have gone through the analysis. I know T(0,0) = 0, because sheep does not need to make any moves. But i did not understand how T(1,0)=T(0,1)=3? To solve the recurrence relation I need to know the value of T(1,0) or T(0,1) which is 3. Can any one explain me clearly? Any help will be appreciated.

https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejamio/round/0000000000050fc5/0000000000054edd

Comment: All information that is needed to understand the question should be inside the question, not behind a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sheep is at (0, 1), one sheepdog will put itself at (0, 2), and the other at either (-1, 1) or (1, 1) (it doesn't matter). Then half the time the sheep will move to the target, the rest of the time to (1, 1) (or (-1, 1) if the sheepdog was on the other side).

From (1, 1), as the question says, the sheepdogs will put themselves at (2, 1) and (1, 2), and the sheep will move to either (1, 0) or (0, 1).

Let E0 be the expected number of steps from (1, 0) (or equivalently (0, 1)), and E1 be the expected number of steps from (1, 1) (or equivalently (-1, 1)).

Then E0 = 1/2 + (1+E1)/2, and E1 = 1+E0.

So E0=1/2 + (1+1+E0)/2 = 3/2 + E0/2, giving E0=3. This also gives E1=4, which agrees with the result in the question.